# TypeScript inner class extending another inner class is not assignable to the superclass (declaration merging)

Tags: typescript

Consider the following MWE, where X is a generic base class that does something with a generic data object, and Y is a concrete implementation of X with its own implementation of the data object.

```js
abstract class X<V, T extends XData<V>> {}

class XData<T> {
    public readonly value: T
    public constructor(value: T) {
        this.value = value
    }
}

class Y<T> extends X<T, YData<T>> {}

class YData<T> extends XData<T> {
    public readonly min: number
    public constructor(value: T, min: number) {
        super(value)
        this.min = min
    }
}
```

If I refactor this code to make the data classes inner classes using [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html), like so:

```js
abstract class A<V, T extends A.Data<V>> {}

namespace A {
    export class Data<T> {
        public readonly value: T
        public constructor (value: T) {
            this.value = value
        }
    }
}

class B<T> extends A<T, B.Data<T>> {}

namespace B {
    export class Data<T> extends A.Data<T> {
        public readonly min: number
        public constructor(value: T, min: number) {
            super(value)
            this.min = min
        }
    }
}
```

then `tsc` starts emitting the error:

```
Class static side 'typeof B' incorrectly extends base class static side 'typeof A'.
  Types of property 'Data' are incompatible.
    Type 'typeof B.Data' is not assignable to type 'typeof A.Data'.
```

`tsc` only complains when *both* of the following are true:

1. Both data classes are merged inner classes.  If I make either data class a top-level class, the compiler emits no error (even if the other is still a merged inner class).
2. The constructor signature of the data subclass differs from the constructor signature of the data superclass.  For example, the following compiles without error:

```js
class C<T> extends A<T, C.Data<T>> {}

namespace C {
    export class Data<T> extends A.Data<T> {
        public readonly min: number
        public constructor(value: T)  {
            super(value)
            this.min = 1
        }
    }
}
```

Despite the error, the compiled ECMAScript is syntactically and semantically correct.  You can trivially modify A and B to do something with a data object to prove this.

Is this a bug, or is there something about declaration merging I don't understand that means the error is legitimate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the error is legitimate and has nothing to do with declaration merging.  Consider the following code:

```
class X {
  static prop: string | number = 123;
}

class Y extends X {
  static prop: string = "y";
} // okay

class Z extends X { // error!
//    ~ <-- boolean not assignable to string | number
  static prop: boolean = false;
}
```

In ESNext, [`static`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static) properties and methods are inherited by subclasses (see [MDN example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static#Examples)).

In TypeScript, when something is inherited, the usual rule is that you can override the inherited thing with something more *specific* but it has to be *assignable to* the overridden thing.  This is usually called the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)... if `X extends Y`, someone should be able to substitute all your `Y` objects with `X` objects and you wouldn't care or notice.

It was [decided](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4628#issuecomment-149333638) to treat the static side of classes this way (well, mostly... more on the exception to come).  Static properties and static methods on subclasses must be assignable to the corresponding static properties and static methods on their superclasses.

So in the code above, `Y` is a valid extension of `X`, because `string` is assignable to `string | number`, but `Z` is *not* a valid extension because it tries to override `prop` in an invalid way, since `boolean` is not assignable to `string | number`.

---

Now, remember when I said the static side of class is only *mostly* inherited via the Liskov Substitution Principle?  The big exception is the constructor function itself... that is, the way you call it with `new`:

```
class V {
  prop: string = "v";
  static statProp: string = "V";
  constructor() {} // no-arg
}

const v = new V();

class W extends V {
  prop: "w" = "w";
  static statPtop: "W" = "W";
  constructor(x: string) { // one-arg
    super();
  }
}

const w = new W("hmm");
```

Here `W` extends `V`, which means that an instance of `W` should be usable as an instance of `V`:

```
const substituteVInstance: V = w; // okay
```

And any of `W`'s instance or static properties should be usable as the corresponding instance or static property of `V`:

```
const substituteVPop: typeof v.prop = w.prop; // okay
const substituteVStaticPop: typeof V.statProp = W.statProp; // okay
```

But the constructor itself is not substitutable:

```
const substituteVConstructor: typeof V = W; // ERROR!
//    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Type 'typeof W' is not assignable to type 'typeof V'.
```

That's because `new W()` is an error, while `new V()` is not.  So you can't always fully substitute the static side of a parent class with the static side of a child class.  It only works if the constructor functions themselves are also assignable:

```
class W2 extends V {
  prop: "w2" = "w2";
  static statProp: "W2" = "W2";
  constructor() {super()}
}
const substituteVConstructorOkay: typeof V = W2; // okay
```

---

Now let's put those two things together and see the fireworks:

```
class A {
  static Data = class DataA {
    constructor() {} // no-arg constructor
  };
}

class B extends A { // error!
  //  ~ <---- typeof DataB not assignable to typeof DataA
  static Data = class DataB extends A.Data {
    constructor(arg: string) { // one-arg constructor
      super();
    } 
  };
}
```

This is the problem you are having.  Class `B` is supposed to extend class `A`, meaning that `B.Data` must be assignable to `A.Data`.  And yes, `B.Data` is a class which is declared to `extends A.Data`.  But `typeof B.Data` is not assignable to `typeof A.Data` because the constructors are not compatible.  You can't call `new B.Data()` with the same arguments you can call `new A.Data()` with, so it's an error.

---

I'm not sure what the best fix is for you here.  Could you maybe make the constructor function in `B.Data` able to take just one argument?  Like this:

```
  namespace B {
    export class Data<T> extends A.Data<T> {
      public readonly min: number;
      public constructor(value: T, min?: number) { // allow one arg
        super(value);
        this.min = min || 0; // pick default value
      }
    }
  }
```

Not sure about your use case, but that at least makes the compiler errors go away.

---

Whew!  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYGwhgzhAEAa0G8CwAoa0IBcyYJbGgAcAnAe0IC4NNjcA7Ac2gB9o6BXAWwCMBTY6AF5oARgBMAZgDcqAL6pUoSDACa0XgA9MvOgBMY8ZGmo58RMpWq1GQ6ACIAnnZkpZ0APTvopANZgHCihKUNAAWupaOvpwiB5e-GTEAISo6J7oAH7QADwAtLnQ3KSkILxgdGykmNDKuAx0YNyl0JikVvRMrBw8-KkmeAQk5FRFJWUVwgBmYCAQvC7yKKieK6uegcEwAGqIfUOWWNZMwnYAbs59WKYEV5gAChZUhx22dlsXxsCkdIfswK3EAAUAEpEG50nRSLkwMQGHINt8sNBTrY6LwAO7QLYglyKcAhADqEW0em2u2M+yodnRdleNJc6FuZlud1aljsBNpJ05DOgXx+ND+AMBGieNA6oIQcW8aOhsL6jPYhH4OL6i0WikR1UxwjRmIJgLsAAtOJw7MDcUEtRh2NwsLhMOxtFsAJIC8rAXhUHbCdFSaW+fyagU2u14R3Ou7DFoOZWkSbIgB0+1s6OTFn96UDAStIYgtvtEd4WwAytgBlHLJhY7x41jEyyLLYCQ3yw9yJmvNng0j82GHU7iwBhLXEIWkYhUatxhM+6AEzvQACiACUVwB5FcpFDpdDQDIHw9H48njLLLwAFRr0AA5NPawmCTfoLgYJDqrV6o1mq0Y8rb-edZbDeiYbPiMAEmIxJRGSRjoJS9jomIXKIchvJMjcbaPPYkEoRyaF9Pyvz-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)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to put together that very detailed answer! Now you've pointed it out I feel pretty stupid... too much time spent thinking in circles and not stepping back to see the big picture!